# Equivalent Linux commands for Windows ones to create user and database

Tags: postgresql, command-line, database-user

There is a manual for configuring PostgreSQL on Windows with these commands:

```
C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createuser.exe --username=postgres --superuser --pwprompt saleor

C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createdb.exe --username=postgres --owner=saleor saleor
```

I'm going to do the same on Linux, but I'm not sure how.

I know that I have to do:

```
> sudo su postgres
> psql 

psql (13.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

But I'm not sure what to do next. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Search for connect to database using psql - maybe \c saleor?

Comment: An linux you would use `createuser` instead of `createuser.exe` and `createdb` instead of `createdb.exe` - but **outside** of `psql`. Or inside `psql` use the SQL commands `create user saleor` and `create database saleor owner saleor`. But that tutorial is pretty bad because it recommends to create that user as a superuser which is a **really** bad idea. A superuser should not be used for regular applications. Applications that require that shouldn't be used

Comment: That's right =) First running `sudo su postgres` an then running `createuser --username=postgres --superuser --pwprompt saleor` seems to be fine :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you post your comment as an answer so that this question can be marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bit openSUSE Tumbleweed with PostgreSQL 13 installed. Just run:

```
> sudo su postgres
> createuser --username=postgres --superuser --pwprompt saleor
> createdb --username=postgres --owner=saleor saleor
```

If the user already exists, it can be deleted by:

```
> sudo su postgres
> dropuser --username=postgres saleor
```

To see a list of users and databases, just run:

```
> sudo su postgres
> psql
# \du
# \l
# \q
```